# How do I listen to mouse position in Python using the module Xlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouselistener, xlib

I know how to get the mouse position in Python with this code calling display.

```
from Xlib import display

data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data 
x = data["root_x"] 
y = data["root_y"]
```

but I have an idea for an application that requires me to act on the mouse when it gets close to the edge of the screen, and its not practical to constantly query those functions, and I can't seem to find any type of mouse listener which would be ideal.

Do you have any idea how to either listen to the mouse events in real-time or another better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Are you sure this relates to [tag:pywin32]? It looks more like [tag:X11].

Comment: This is not "in Python". It is with a particular library. You have to say which library you are using. Where does `display` come from?

Comment: You need to set up an event thread, and listen for PointerMotionMask events.  You will get a callback for every mouse movement, so make sure your code is efficient.